# dd an image to SD card finished, SD card still busy

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, dd

If I'm using dd to restore an *.img file to an SD card, it works without problems. If I try to safely remove (eject in nautilus) the SD card right after dd is finished, a notification is poping up which says: "Something is writing to SD card". The LED on the card reader is blinking as well. It takes a couple minutes until it's possible to remove the card. First question is, how can that be?

I'm using dd in a bash script. As soon as the script is finished it should be possible to remove the SD card. Second question is, can I somehow check the status of the SD card which means busy or not?

Edit 20170203:
This is the script. The purpose is just to restore an raspberry pi backup.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#enter path of image
IMG=$(whiptail --inputbox "Enter path to image." 8 78 "$HOME/Downloads/raspberry_backup.img.gz" --title "Name" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

exitstatus=$?
if [ $exitstatus != 0 ]; then
    echo "INFO: User abort."
    exit 1
fi

#check for dependencies
if [ -z "$(which parted 2> /dev/null)" ] || [ -z "$(which gzip 2> /dev/null)" ]; then
    if (whiptail --title "Dependencies" --yesno "This script need parted and gzip. One or more are not installed. Install now?" 8 78) then
        sudo dnf install -y parted gzip
    else
        exit 1
    fi
fi

#show information of drives
whiptail --scrolltext --title "Info about mounted devices:" --msgbox "$(sudo parted -l -m init G print | grep /dev/sd | cut -d: -f1,2)" 8 78

#enter drive name
DEV=$(whiptail --inputbox "Enter Device Name." 8 78 /dev/sd --title "Device Name" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

exitstatus=$?
if [ $exitstatus != 0 ]; then
    echo "INFO: User abort."
    exit 1
fi

#check for /dev/sd* vaidity
if [[ $DEV != "/dev/sd"* ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: ${DEV} is not valid."
    exit 1
fi

#if restore image is *.gz then uncomress first
if [[ "$IMG" == *".gz" ]]; then
    (pv -n ${IMG} | gzip -d -k > $HOME/raspberry_restore.img) 2>&1 | whiptail --gauge "Please wait while uncompressing image..." 6 50 0
    IMG=$HOME/raspberry_restore.img
fi

if [[ "$IMG" == *".img" ]]; then
    SIZEDD=$(sudo parted -m $IMG unit B print | grep ext4 | cut -d: -f3 | cut -dB -f1)
    (sudo dd if=$IMG bs=1M | pv -n --size $SIZEDD | sudo dd of=$DEV bs=1M) 2>&1 | whiptail --gauge "Please wait while restoring image to SD card..." 6 50 0
else
    echo "ERROR: Not an *.img file"
    exit 1
fi

sudo rm $HOME/raspberry_restore.img

#show information
whiptail --title "Restore finished." --msgbox "Restored to path: "$DEV"" 8 78
exit 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your script?

Comment: The easy answer is to run `sync`, and wait for it to exit before removing the device. (Even more directly, one could call the `fsync()` syscall on the block device itself).

Comment: btw, you've got some miscellaneous bugs around missing quotes and such; http://shellcheck.net/ will find them. And you probably want `"Restored to path: \"$DEV\""` to make the inner quotes literal rather than syntactic. And all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: By the way, it looks like there are a bunch of places where you're using parens for grouping. Parenthesis tell the shell to create a subshell, so they actually have performance impact on your code (and change semantics around variable scope). If you just want a grouping operator, use curly braces instead.

Comment: Thanks for this tips as well. I'm a just a beginner...

Comment: ...for example: `{ pv -n "$IMG" | gzip -d -k > "$HOME/raspberry_restore.img"; } 2>&1` avoids running the pipeline inside a separate subshell. (Swapped out the curly braces in `${IMG}`, which do nothing particularly useful, for quotes -- which suppress string-splitting and glob expansion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fsync()` syscall will cause any write caching at the OS level to be flushed. While something could be written in C to call this for the specific block device at hand, from the shell, your easiest way to get there in shell is using the `sync` command to flush all pending writes, across all filesystems and devices:

```
sync
```

---

Alternately, you can tell `dd` to use the `O_SYNC` flag, by passing `oflag=sync`, preventing `dd` from exiting until the write is persisted to disk:

```
# note that oflag is a GNU extension, not found on MacOS/BSD
dd oflag=nocache,sync of="$DEV" bs=1M
```

If you know the native block size for your SD card, consider using `O_DIRECT` instead:

```
# 4k is a reasonable guess on block size; tune based on your actual hardware.
dd oflag=direct of="$DEV" bs=4K
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using this very quick perl script described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/216628

I've used myself sometimes too to find unwanted/hidden/unknown processes that keeps resources busy.

Once you get the process, the inner behaviour that keeps your SSD busy can be investigated.

Comment: No, if that's the problem, as that script uses the kernel's virtual memory block dump mechanism, you'll still see writes actions even if they are left pending in the kernel.

Comment: You're right -- I made an unfounded assumption about mechanism. Apologies about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lsof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) if something is using the device. If your SD card is identified as `/dev/sdd`:

```
lsof /dev/sdd 2>/dev/null && echo "device is busy"
```

Comment: lsof doesn't works for me. The card reader is still blinking and nautilus doesnt't allow me to remove the card.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. It tells us if any files are open, but it doesn't tell you if the block cache has unflushed writes, which is the situation the OP is in after `dd` completes but their device is still in use.

Comment: Maybe you should write an answer to use 'sync' then.